# Cruise control switch 2008 Jeep Compass

Tags: troubleshooting, jeep, replace, cruise-control, switches

Could anyone tell me how to replace the cruise control switch on my 2008 jeep compass? Where it is on the steering wheel is a bad place. I got into my car and smacked it with my knee and broke it. I have a Haynes manual but it tell me nothing. I have also search youtube and the internet. I just need to know if i should take it somewhere or is it simple enough to do myself. Thanks.

Comment: It's usually pretty simple to replace, but I've never done it on a Compass. Look on YouTube for "turn signal stalk" or "multi-switch" ... maybe your Google Fu just wasn't kicking in. :o) I'd look for you, but I'm only on my phone app.

Comment: THANK YOU for the guide you posted. It was invaluable. I would add that a #25 Torx head bit, is the essential bit. The bolts on either side of the steering wheel to remove the air bag, are 10mm. :) I had to go looking for the right size torx bit & those can be really fun if you aren't sure where they went. ;) Leslea in Alberta.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove the airbag from the steering wheel.  There are screws on the side.

**You MUST disconnect the battery negative terminal and let the vehicle sit for a few minutes before proceeding.**

[image]

Disconnect the electrical connector for the horn bracket and remove the 3 screws.

[image]

Disconnect the cruise control stalk electrical connection, and the small screws that hold it.

[image]

You may have guessed it:  Assembly is simply the reverse of removal.